# Can we see the Eigen Vector Spans from the geometric transformation (meaning) of a Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I am watching [3b1b](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYB8IZa5AuE&t=3s) on linear transformations and the geometric meaning of the transformation matrices to the vector space.

I can see that how the matrix can do a transformation to the vector space of the original vector domain to a transformed domain.

But on a side note, I know the geometric interpretation of eigen vectors, that they when applied by the transformation represented by the matrix are spanned in their direction only.

So, we can do see from the transformation of the basis vectors ( $i$ and $j$ ) and the gridlines caused by the matrix the manner in which the space is transformed.

But, how to see from the Matrix and the geometric transformation that it is representing, those spans that are eigenvectors, i.e. **those lines that are just stretched or flipped**?

For example, the shear matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}

will move the original space into a shear. I can see the gridlines. But from this geometric transformation, how to see **those lines in the original space that are retained in span** even after the transformation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From a routine calculation  you can see that the only eigenvectors are those of the form $\begin{pmatrix}a\\0\end{pmatrix}$.  The eigenvalue is $1$, so the transformation just returns the same eigenvector.

Note that $\vec i$  lands on itself, and $\vec j$ lands on $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you! I am getting the same, but I wanted to see the eigen values from the geometric meaning of the Transformation Matrix, which is changing the vectors from original vector space to transformed vector space. In this transformation only, I am trying to see those spans that are preserved!  So, basically trying to see eigen values from the geometric meaning of Matrices.

Comment: Like we can see the Matrix is shear transformation Matrix and if applied to any vector space, it will keep the horizontal grid lines in same span, but the vertical grid lines are twisted and glided to the right. So, I can see that $i$ is one of the eigen vector, i.e. $[1, 0]$ from the geometric meaning of the Transformation matrix. But how to see those preserved spans in other cases, like for example here only how to conclude with guarantee from the geometric meaning of transformation that it don't have any other span that is preserved?

Comment: The transformation is nonsingular and the only proper subspaces are $1$-dimensional, so not much more can be said, I don't think.  The $x$-axis is preserved.  And any $2$-dimensional subspace is the whole thing, so it will be preserved under the isomorphism.